# How to show line numbering in nano when opening a file

Tags: nano

Is there a way to tell nano to automatically show line numbering each time I open a file?

Comment: `set linenumbers` in nanorc does the trick

Comment: CTRL+3 then SHIFT+3 will show line numbers
CTRL+3 then SHIFT+3 will hide the line numbers

Comment: Starting from nano 2.7.1 you can open file with `-l` (`--linenumbers`) flag to display lilne numbers beside the text.

Comment: `ALT` + `SHIFT` + `#` will work in ubuntu

Comment: Best way is probably to edit the Nano config file: the example config file is located at `/usr/share/doc/nano/examples/sample.nanorc`. Copy this file to your `~/.nanorc` and start editing from there.

Comment: For all the `.nanorc` options see [NANORC](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nanorc.5.html).

Comment: Better yet: install the [`micro` editor](https://micro-editor.github.io/). It is a CLI tool with mouse support. Shows line numbers automatically. Download the executable with `curl https://getmic.ro | bash`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples JEEZ! Thats PRETTY good.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado, one thing that annoys me is how slow Ctrl + C is to copy inside `micro`. If you figure out a way to speed it up, [leave a reply here](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro/issues/1569#issuecomment-1387390921).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

According to the man page for GNU nano 2.9.3 (also verified on version 4.8) , you have two options for automatically opening with line-numbers shown and one for toggling them on/off once nano is open:

#### Command Line Flags

You can use the `-l` or `--linenumbers` flags.

```
       -l, --linenumbers
              Display line numbers to the left of the text area.
```

e.g.

```
nano -l foo.txt
nano --linenumbers foo.txt
```

#### Via the config file(s)

Alternatively, according to the man page for nanorc, you can add `set linenumbers` in `~/.nanorc`, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nano/nanorc` or `~/.config/nano/nanorc`.

```
INITIALIZATION FILE
       nano will read two configuration files: first the system's  nanorc  (if
       it exists), and then the user's nanorc (if it exists), either ~/.nanorc
       or $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nano/nanorc or ~/.config/nano/nanorc, whichever  is
       encountered  first.  See nanorc(5) for more information on the possible
       contents of those files.
```

```
       set linenumbers
          Display line numbers to the left of the text area.
```

So the contents of my ~/.nanorc file are simply:

```
 1 set linenumbers
 2
```

#### Via a key bindings

Not exactly what the OP was asking for, but for completeness you can also toggle line number on/off via the default keybinding (as of v4.8) of `Alt+N`.

Alternatively you can rebind this key via the man file mentioned method:

```
REBINDING KEYS
       Key bindings can be changed via the following three commands:

          bind key function menu
                 Rebinds the given key to the given function in the given menu (or in all menus where the function exists when all is used).
```

```
The format of key should be one of:

          ^X     where X is a Latin letter, or one of several ASCII characters (@, ], \, ^, _), or the word "Space".  Example: ^C.

          M-X    where X is any ASCII character except [, or the word "Space".  Example: M-8.

          Sh-M-X where X is a Latin letter.  Example: Sh-M-U.  By default, each Meta+letter keystroke does the same as the corresponding Shift+Meta+letter.  But when any Shift+Meta bind is made, that  will
                 no longer be the case, for all letters.

          FN     where N is a numeric value from 1 to 24.  Example: F10.  (Often, F13 to F24 can be typed as F1 to F12 with Shift.)

          Ins or Del.

       Rebinding ^M (Enter) or ^I (Tab) is probably not a good idea.  On some terminals it's not possible to rebind ^H (unless --raw is used) because its keycode is identical to that of the Backspace key.

       Valid function names to be bound are:

...

linenumbers
            Toggles the display of line numbers in front of the text.
```

#### Regarding alternate config files:

In response to comments about alternate config files, from the description of `man nanorc`:

```
During startup, nano  will  first
       read  the system-wide settings, from /etc/nanorc (the exact path might be different on your
       system), and then the user-specific settings,  either  from  ~/.nanorc  or  from  $XDG_CON‐
       FIG_HOME/nano/nanorc or from ~/.config/nano/nanorc, whichever is encountered first.
```

I would not typically advise others to change the system-wide config file, unless you have a good reason to do so, as it will likely be overwritten during any updates, and is not likely to be included in system backups, which typically only include the home directory.

#### Using with sudo

As noted by a commenter, this may not work as expected if you have to use sudo with nano, e.g. `sudo nano myFile`. This is because when you use sudo you are doing whatever comes after `sudo` as the "super user", thus the name (super user do ..). If you edited your non-super user config file (e.g. `~/.nanorc` or `/home/myUserName/.nanorc`) this will not be run when you use sudo as you are not running nano as `myUserName` any longer. Thus, you have a few options.

1. The simplest is just to use the `-l` flag and it will work as is.
2. Copy the contents of your `~/.nanorc` to `/root/.nanorc` as this represents the home directory for the super user. Assuming you have your `./nanorc` file setup as you like, and you don't already have a `/root/.nanorc` file then you can just run `sudo cp ~/.nanorc /root/`. Note this will overwrite any existing nanorc file in `/root`.

Comment: -l works.  However, note that instead of /home/<username>/.nanorc your file may be at /etc/nanorc

Comment: @Chiwda I guess you can (didn't verify), but I'd guess anything you change in /etc/nanorc will be overwritten upon any updates, and isn't included in a common backup scheme, thus the recommendation to use the user-config one in your home directory instead.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist in the home directory, can I just make a copy of /etc/nanorc into home and that will override /etc/nanorc?

Comment: @Chiwda, you shouldn't have to copy anything. Just a blank file with 'set linenumbers' on the first line should be fine. As spec'd in the man file, nano will "first read the system-wide settings, from /etc/nanorc" ... then read your user defined one, thus no need to provide the same settings twice.

Comment: Note that this will not show linenumbers if you have to `sudo nano` a file. (Unfortunately, I have no solution for this)

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer accordingly. See the new last section on this.

Answer (score 427):

The keyboard combination to display the current line number whilst you are using nano is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Alternatively, to display the line & column number position you could just use the `-c` parameter when launching nano i.e:

```
nano -c [filename]
```

To make this permanent, `nano` uses a configuration in your home folder `~/.nanorc`

Thus to display line numbers always when using nano...

```
nano ~/.nanorc
```

(don't worry if its empty - this file doesn't exist by default)

type `set constantshow`

N.B. the deprecated syntax `set const` is shown in the animation

Save

[image]

---

[image: animation1]

Since you are using line numbers remember you can use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to jump to a specific line number.

Comment: If you are in a tty, an alternative to CTRL+C is F11 and an alternative to ALT+G is F13 (which doesn't exist on my keyboard) or  Ctrl+_ (Ctrl+Shift+-).

Comment: Note that `-c` might not behave the way people are expecting. It won't prefix each line with the number (like `less -N`), it just makes the status box at the bottom of the screen permanent.

Comment: I agree with @IanDunn, this is the wrong answer. Add `set linenumbers` instead (only works in recent versions).

Comment: The permanent solution listed here no longer works in ubuntu 16.04+. Does anyone have an updated solution to permanently activating this setting in Ubuntu 16.04+ ?

Comment: @DanRan why it should not work? The post has high vote so it might work... the better the answer the higher the vote? Welcome to the SE Network.

Comment: A more linux style permanent solution is `echo set constantshow>> ~/.nanorc`

Answer (score 155):

Accidentally found nice shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>, which in some keyboard layouts can be done with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

[image: click me gently]

Comment: doesnt work for me on ubuntu16.04 with GNU nano 2.5.3

Comment: does not work with mac keyboard on ssh'd ubuntu terminal

Comment: Add `set linenumbers` to `.nanorc` to make it permanent. If the shortcut doesn't work try `Modifier key + #`.

Comment: It works on Raspbian

Comment: @Gregor Godier Thanks alot this is great with `set linenumbers` in nanorc

Comment: New versions can be downloaded from here: https://www.nano-editor.org/download.php

Comment: Stumbled across this keyboard shortcut when making a typo and was pleasantly surprised :D

Comment: great, works on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: `ALT+SHIFT+3` found working on win 10 inside super putty

Comment: `Ctrl + 3` then `Shift + 3` toggles line numbering, for those who can't get it to work.

Comment: @DirkSchumacher `esc + n` and `esc + shift + #` work on macOS.

Comment: On my dell laptop the shortcut is `ALT + AltGr + #`

Answer (score 28):

Compile Nano from source:

```
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/nano.git;cd nano;./autogen.sh;./configure;sudo make install
```

Then add the following to your `.nanorc` file:

```
set linenumbers
```

You can use <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> to turn line numbers on and off from within Nano.

Comment: Actually like that. See you did 2 commits, was the 2nd one, (size increase..) because of the 1st one?

Comment: Yes, that was because of the first one.

Comment: I do like this better than set const or now set constantshow so took the liberty to put in a ppa using 2.6.2 release for ubuntu 16.04.  If you wish me to credit or whatever differently let me know.. https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/nano-lined

Comment: Oh cool, thanks for that! I don't mind getting or not getting credited, it just makes me happy to see people finding something I did useful, besides most of the code there belongs to the maintainers of nano, not me.

Comment: Sweet.  I've submitted a request to merge this into nano at nano's savannah page: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?49217

Comment: Don't worry, I'm already working with Benno on merging this: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/nano-devel/2016-09/msg00061.html

Comment: This has been merged upstream and will be available in the next release of Nano
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/nano-devel/2016-10/msg00074.html

Comment: available with `nano 2.7.1+`

Comment: this implies that you have to compile from source to set `set linenumbers`

Comment: Which was and may still be correct when it comes to Ubuntu

Comment: In my case, set linenumbers is enough, without recompiling nano from source

Answer (score 14):

If `nano -c filename` does not work, use `nano filename` then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>_</kbd>. It will ask you for the line number to go to.

Comment: I'm using SSH and that keyboard shortcut makes the text smaller :(

Comment: That's because you are effectively zooming out with `Ctrl`+`-`. Instead you need `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`-` to get the underscore.

Answer (score 8):

It's 2021. The OP's question is still valid, but many of the answers here are for an older version of `nano`. I'm not presenting this answer as ["the last word"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/last+word) - only as an update.

> The default screen of nano consists of five areas. From top to bottom these are: the title bar, a blank line, the edit window, the status bar, and two help lines.

### Where to display line numbers?

Line numbers may be displayed in one of two places:

1. the edit window
2. the status bar

The status bar display simply updates the line number (and column) of the cursor/insertion point as it's moved about in the edit window. Line numbers in the edit window are positioned in the left margin. It is possible to display the line number in either or both the edit window and the status bar.

### Display line numbers in the edit window:

There are several methods (this is not necessarily a complete list):

1. Before the file is opened:

   Edit/create the file `~/.nanorc` with the following line:

   ```
   set linenumbers
   ```
2. When the file is opened:

   Use the `-l` option in `nano`:

   ```
   $ nano -l <myfilename>
   ```
3. After the file is opened:

   Toggle line numbers "on" and "off" w/ `alt-shift-#`:

   <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>#</kbd>

### Display line numbers in the status bar

1. Before the file is opened:

   Edit/create the file `~/.nanorc` with the following line:

   ```
   set constantshow
   ```
2. When the file is opened:

   Use the `-c` option in `nano`:

   ```
   $ nano -c <myfilename>
   ```
3. After the file is opened:

   Toggle line number display in the status bar "on" and "off" w/ `alt-shift-C`:

   <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

### Summary

These all work as of today: Ubuntu 20.04, `nano --version` = GNU nano, version 4.8, although there are minor discrepancies in [the documentation.](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.8/nano.html)

Comment: `set linenumbers` did not work for me in `nano` `version 2.8.3`. Command is not found and gives an error upon start.

Comment: @bomben: As I said in the first paragraph, time marches on, and `nano` seems to be a rudderless ship, changing direction seemingly at random. Please feel free to edit this answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you have already opened the file with nano you press

```
Ctrl+w+t
```

(not simultaneusly, press control and w, then without letting go control and letting go w, press t)

This command will require column and line, you enter them this way:

```
10,23 (enter)
```

and you will end up in line 10 character 23.

If you are at the top of the file and you only want to find the line:

```
Ctrl+w+t and then 10
```

If you are at a acertain line and you want to find the column:

```
Ctrl+w+t and then ,23
```

If you haven't opened the file yet, you can do this:

```
nano +10,23 file (enter)
```

and the file will open with cursor in the line 10, chanracter 23, so you can try also:

```
nano +10 file (enter)
```

`nano +,23 file (enter)` (Note that this will send you to the character 23 of the first line only)

Comment: This may be the correct way to find the line in the terminal however it does not answer the question on how to make it automatically show on opening.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me to find a line number....none of the above worked in my instance of nano.

Comment: Same as Ctrl+G?

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me on MacOS Catalina.