# How to display line numbers in Nano text editor

Tags: text, editor, nano

When using Nano text editor, how can I display line numbers so I can see the lines that I am getting error messages about.  I have a lengthy program and am getting an error message for line 95 and 125 for example.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will show the current line/column once, and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (usually <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) will toggle a continuous line/column display on and off.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> (that's underscore, so on most keyboard layouts that's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) will prompt you to jump to a specific line number.

Answer (score 4):

**Non permanent**

```
nano -c /path/to/file
```

**Permanent**

edit `~/.nanorc` and add the following

```
set const
```

For more details - as mentioned by Nick - check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73444/how-to-show-line-numbering-in-nano-when-opening-a-file) perfect answer.

Comment: set constantshow