# Error when using sudo apt-get update in line 54 of the list

Tags: 16.04, software-center, sudo

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Whenever I try to install updates using the terminal window, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCvWH.png).

Also when I go into the Software Center there is software shown.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sudo is working fine, you my guess is you edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` and have a typo.

Open an editor an comment out line 54

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Find line 54 and remove it

See also [How to show line numbering in nano when opening a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73444/how-to-show-line-numbering-in-nano-when-opening-a-file) for information on how to show and go to specific lines with nano.

If you need help, post the contents of the file, better line 54.

Comment: sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev

;

Please help.

Comment: And how do I remove lines?

Comment: delete button or back space. Arrow keys to navigate